# I want to sort my store in sencha touch facing issues

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have many fields in my object like {id, trackName , mtp , mtpDisplay}
I am using below store method to sort data by mtp field.but its setting mtpDisplay to 0.

```
 renderTodayEntriesView: function (startIndex, endIndex) {
    entriesStore = Ext.getStore('TodaysEntryTrackStore');
    entriesStore.data.sort('mtp','ASC');
   // After this mtpDisplay is settingt to 0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to this: [extjs - Sort store alphanumerically and case insensitively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479675/extjs-sort-store-alphanumerically-and-case-insensitively) . Implement the function on the first answer and call it whenever you need to sort your data.